# Accessing Return value from function using apscheduler

Tags: python, apscheduler

```
from apscheduler.scheduler.background() import BackgroundScheduler

def func():
   a= 1
   return a

scheduler.add_job(func,'interval',seconds=10)
scheduler.start()
```

The simple function above returns 'a'. How can I access this value through the `apscheduler`?

Comment: `func()` accesses the value

Comment: You should be scheduling a different function, that calls `func()` and does something with its return value.